# How Select From Multiple Entity into a new Object with Room-Database?

Tags: java, android, error-handling, android-sqlite, android-room

I Have this tow POJOs For RoomDB Entity

```
@Entity
public class Favorite {...}
```

```
@Entity
public class ProductCart {
    Integer productQuantity;
    ...
}
```

I need to apply this `select` statment and return it inside the object `FavoriteAdapterData`

```
SELECT favorite.*,
       (SELECT CASE count(productQuantity)
               WHEN 0 THEN 0
                      ELSE productQuantity
               END  FROM ProductCart 
        WHERE favorite.id = productId) AS cartQuantity
FROM Favorite favorite
```

[Sqlite statment test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcwBe.png)

```
public class FavoriteAdapterData {
    int cartQuantity = 0;
    Favorite favorite;
    ...
}
```

*I try the following code*

```
@Query("SELECT  " +
            "      (    SELECT CASE count(productQuantity) " +
            "           WHEN 0  THEN 0 " +
            "                   ELSE productQuantity  " +
            "           END  " +
            "           FROM ProductCart " +
            "           WHERE productId = favorite.id" +
            "       ) AS cartQuantity" +
            "       ,favorite.* " +
            "FROM Favorite favorite")
    LiveData<List<FavoriteAdapterData>> getFavoriteProducts();
```

But It didn't work and Android Studio notfi me this error:

```
Cannot figure out how to read this field from a cursor. 
Favorite favorite; 
             ^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to Embed the Favorite class within the FavoriteAdapterData class using the **[@Embedded](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/Embedded)** annotation, then it will determine the columns and outputfields from the Favorite class's fields/variables

e.g. :-

```
public class FavoriteAdapterData {
    int cartQuantity = 0;
    @Embedded
    Favorite favorite;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks It worked, I tried it before and the app crashed, so I assumed it's not the right way to use @Embedded, but after struggling with my code I found inside the adapter who use FavoriteAdapterData a stupid null value makeing the app crash. 

Comment: @AimanAlyosofi that's good that you got it working. If this answered your question then you could consider ticking it as the answer.